How to scrape sites like Bloomberg?
So i am trying out a new web-scraping project and I wanted to get the data from sites like Bloomberg and FinancialTimes.
I am using Selenium in Python, when I run the script to just trint the whole body of the page
html = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').get_attribute("innerHTML")

I get a few thousand lines of code, most of them inside script tags. If I compare the page source from Chrome's Inspect(Ctrl+Shift+I), it looks nothing like what I just scraped. I cannot even accept the cookies.
Is there something that I can do about this, a workaround maybe? Or am I doing something wrong?

"Is there something that I can do about this" Yes: use an API.

How do you propose to bypass Captcha?

The Body Tag's inner-Html is the entire visible and hidden body of the page.
If I had to guess, it is indecipherable because they used a framework to construct their website, such as react or reflex. This would make it extremely hard to navigate by element class_name and other methods.
What I recommend is using the Selenium IDE. Download it for firefox or chrome as an extension. start a project, go to the website that you want to scrape, do all the activities you need, and the IDE will automatically generate the source code in your language of choice.
selenium extension here
Most of the time when i use selenium i end up searching by xpath or using
driver.execute_script(f"<js function>")
because websites are so abstracted now days.
